# How is the あ vowel produced?

Tags: phonetics

I've been reading about the sounds of Japanese and always thought the あ's highest point is shown as in this diagram:

[image]

Which I learned narrowly can be transcribed like [ɑ̞] (the diagram is taken from [here](https://www.imabi.net/japanesephonology.htm), which my book also shows it as)

But reading more, I stumble upon for example from the [Japanese wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E9%9F%B3%E9%9F%BB) this one:

[image]

Which one would be the most correct in most cases?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a diagram of a mouth?

Comment: @istrasci Yes, it's like if you look from the left of someone's head, and the left side of this diagram is the front while the right is the back of the mouth-insides.

Comment: Web searches suggest that [日本語のアは広母音/a/。国際音声字母では前舌の広母音を/a/、 後舌の広母音を/ɑ/と書き分けるが日本語のアはいずれかに決めることはできない](http://daijirin.dual-d.net/extra/nihongoon.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, there is no set-in-stone answer as the difference in pronunciation is slight. As you said, the pronunciation depends on context.